# How to handle problems with RPATH on Mac OS X while installing cmocka?

Tags: c, macos, cmake, rpath, cmocka

I am trying to install and run `cmocka` library for unit testing on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, but **I've got some problems with the `RPATH` settings.**

#### Update:

Thanks to @baf, I was able to include `cmocka.h` in my CMakeLists.txt manually like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-I/usr/local/include/cmocka.h")
```

**However, why is it so that I have to do it manually?**

---

I've already tried many different ways of installing it:

#### What I've done so far:

1. Download cmocka from here: [here](https://cmocka.org/files/1.0/cmocka-1.0.1.tar.xz). Version 1.0.
2. `tar xvf cmocka-1.0.1.tar.xz`
3. `cd cmocka-1.0.1`, `mkdir build` and `cd build`
4. `sudo cmake ..`
   I get a message like this here:

> -- Configuring done
>
> CMake Warning (dev):
>
> Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
>
> MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:
>
> cmocka_shared
>
> This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

## Question #1: How can I set the `rpath` so that there is no warning like the one above?

5. sudo `make`
6. sudo `make install`
7. `cmocka` should be installed now, right?

---

#### Running `cmake` for my program which is using `cmocka` library.

So now I run `cmake` for my program and my main `CMakeList.txt` file has lines like this:

```
find_library (CMOCKA cmocka)
if (NOT CMOCKA)
    message (WARNING "Cmocka library not found.")
endif (NOT CMOCKA)
```

But the warning doesn't show up during this phase, so I believe that `find_libarary(CMOCKA cmocka)` has successfully located `cmocka` on my computer.

#### Running `make` for my program.

While running `make` I get an error like this:

> ```
> fatal error:<br>
>     'cmocka.h' file not found<br>
> #include <cmocka.h>
>           ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

So I guess that `cmocka` cannot be found...

## Question #2: Why `cmocka` library cannot be found?

---

#### Additional notes:

1. I've tried running

   ```
   $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

but it didn't helped. I guess it is a solution for Linux, not Mac.

2. I've tried to learn something about `RAPTH` on Mac in `cmake` from their official documentation here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling. However I understood very little and I wasn't able to come up with a solution for my problem.
3. I've tried installing `cmocka` using `brew` but I got the same result.
4. Moreover, I've read many questions at SO about `RPATH`, linking and `cmocka`, but I couldn't find a suitable solution as well. Nevertheless, here is the list of related threads:

   - [How to set the runtime path (-rpath) of an executable with gcc under Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513799/how-to-set-the-runtime-path-rpath-of-an-executable-with-gcc-under-mac-osx)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721183/getting-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-when-trying-to-build-on-osx
   - [How to configure scons to link using rpath on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271791/how-to-configure-scons-to-link-using-rpath-on-mac)
   - [mariadb install failure: make (Mac OSX 10.6.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043292/mariadb-install-failure-make-mac-osx-10-6-8)
5. I've run `otool -L cmocka`. Here's what I got:

   > ```
   > error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: cmocka (No such file or directory)
   > ```

Comment: Error message is not about missing library, but missing file. Header `cmocka.h` is not in compiler's include path. Try to add `-I/path/to/the/header` to the compiler options.

Comment: @baf. I've found `cmocka.h` in `/usr/local/include/cmocka.h`. I've set such flags for my debug build: `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic -g -I/usr/local/include/cmocka.h")`. However, when running `make` `cmocka.h` is still not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Specify location of the header: `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: It works now. Thank you @bef. Nevertheless, I'm quite curious, why I have to include it using `-I/usr/local/include`... Should it locate cmocka automatically? What is the role of `RPATH` here?

Comment: It seems `/usr/local/include` directory is not in your compiler's include search path. `Rpath` may help to find libraries if installed in non-standard location, but not headers.

Comment: Ok, so RPATH has nothing to do with the "question #2"? *(this would explain why `cmake` was successful)* So it is everything ok with my RPATH settings, right? The problem lies in the difficulty of locating proper headers by my compiler, am I right? If so, what should I search for in order to learn about it and fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully compile my program (thanks to baf) when I added the `-I/usr/local/include` flag to my debug flags:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic -g -I/usr/local/include/cmocka.h")
```